# Broken dependencies after attempting to install ApacheOpenOffice

Tags: installation, hard-drive, libreoffice

So a few days ago i tried installing ApacheOpenOffice, and the instructions i read was to uninstall LibreOffice-Common so i did that with the terminal. Then all the sudden I’m seeing all these errors come up and I’m getting confused. So i uninstall ApacheOpenOffice and just try to go back to LibreOffice. And i get these errors: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6763795/ If this keeps happening I’m going to be left with just having to reinstall Ubuntu. If i do so I'll make sure to check the MD5SUM of the ISO this time. But if anyone can help me fix this i would be happy.

Answer (score -1):

try to run this command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

if it does not work try removing java and re-installing it again

Comment: As shown in my errors i have tried "sudo apt-get -f install" however i seem to not even be able to uninstall java so now i think my package management system is broken. I think I’ll have just backup my system and re install Ubuntu and I’ll just have to be careful this time. But thanks anyway.

Comment: try sudo apt-get purge java